# How to replace Single Quote while loading to Mysql using Python?

Tags: python, mysql

I'm writing a python code to load a csv dataset to MySQL for the client. The requirements are that they will just load the data without opening the dataset. Therefore the code is a bit different from normal loading codes. I have completed writing the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

# In[1]:
import string
import csv
import mysql.connector
import re

# In[2]:
mydb=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="password",autocommit=True)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

# In[3]:
sql_str=''
sql_str1=''
field_name=[]
line=1
file_name=input("\nFile name with extension:")
delimiter_=input('\nDelimiter used:')
textquali=input('\nText Qualifier used Press Enter if no qualifier:')

# In[4]:
mycursor.execute("drop table if exists  rd.pbc_gl_sigline_src")
#r"C:\Users\rcsid\Documents\Office Programs\Working prog\MOCK_DATA.csv"
#re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]\n\.', '_', row)
reader = csv.DictReader(open(file_name,encoding='utf-8',errors='ignore'), delimiter=delimiter_,quotechar=textquali)
rowHeaders = reader.fieldnames
print(rowHeaders)
for i in rowHeaders:
    field_name.append(re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '_', i))
#print(field_name)
#print(f'''create table rd.data_with_header ( {" varchar(100), ".join(field_name)} varchar(100))''')
sql_str=f'''create table rd.pbc_gl_sigline_src ( {" varchar(250), ".join(field_name)} varchar(100))'''
mycursor.execute(sql_str)
for row in reader:
    line=line+1
    sql_str1=f"""insert into rd.pbc_gl_sigline_src values ('{"',' ".join(row.values())}')"""
    print(line)
    print(sql_str1)
    mycursor.execute(sql_str1)
    print("Loaded to pbc_gl_sigline_src")

# In[ ]:
```

The code is working fine and loading the data lines. The issue I am facing is that as the code is building the insert code using a number of single quotes therefore when a data value has a single quote in it that line is getting an error.

```
Example: "sam", "New York City", "123'434" , "houseSTX"
The error is showing that there is a syntax error right to houseSTX
```

Is there a way to replace the Single quotes in the data while loading them using : sql_str1=f"""insert into rd.pbc_gl_sigline_src values ('{"',' ".join(row.values())}')""".  I tried to use the replace function in the code but that did not go as planned. Any help would be much appreciated. Please do update my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use string concatenation to create the query, use placeholders and parameters.

```
placeholders = ", ".join(['%s']*len(field_name))
sql_str1=f"""insert into rd.pbc_gl_sigline_src values ({placeholders})"""
for row in reader:
    mycursor.execute(sql_str1, tuple(row.values()))
```

Comment: I added the code  but this is giving me an error : mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)' at line 1

Comment: The `%s` are supposed to be replaced with the values from `row.values()`. I don't know why that's not working for you.

Comment: Hi, the update I made :

placeholders=", ".join(['%s']*len(field_name))
sql_str1=f"""insert into rd.pbc_gl_sigline_src values ({placeholders})"""
for row in reader:
    line=line+1
    print(line)
    print(sql_str1)
    mycursor.execute(sql_str1,row.values())

mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)' at line 1

Comment: Try using `tuple(row.values())`.